# difference between foo = createFoo() and foo = new Foo()

Tags: javascript, prototype

what difference is there between the following two ways of creating an object in JavaScript

```
function createFoo(){
    var _foo = { id: 1 };
    return _foo;
}
var foo = createFoo();
```

and

```
function Foo(){
    this.id = 1;
}
var foo2 = new Foo();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Running the code in the chrome console give us more information about the content of the 2 variables:

```
> foo
Object {id: 1}
> foo2
Foo {id: 1}
```

So there is a difference.
Spoiler Alert !! The answer lies in the prototype chain:

```
> foo.__proto__
Object {}
> foo2.__proto__
Foo {}
```

If you need more details, refer to this great post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/2523414

Answer (score 0):

There are many differents in the way of instantiating objects that are created and accessed from these functions. For example:

```
function createFoo(){
   var _foo = { id: 1 };
   return _foo;
}
var foo = createFoo();
```

If you want to get value of `id` property, you have to iterate over properties in foo object, like this:

```
for(var prop in foo){
   //if you want to set new value then
   foo[prop] = 5;
   //then getting value is like this
   console.log(foo[prop]);
}
```

In your second example it is different in way of getting/setting value:

```
function Foo(){
    this.id = 1;
} 
var foo2 = new Foo();
foo2.id = 2;//set new value
console.log(foo2.id);
```

That is all I can think of.